# Extjs 4.X How Can we draw Flow Chart components like line and Circle and position them on panel

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am using Ext 4.2.

I wanted to create the structure using Ext component, something like as shown in the attached image.

Can you please suggest me How can I achieved this?

like 
[image]

1] Line with Arrow

2] Circle, For that I think we can use split.

3] Position the Objects, One circle above one is down side etc.

Comment: There's nothing built in to do that, you would need to create and position `Ext.draw.Sprite` objects yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link and i guess u'll get ur answer 
(http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.draw.Component.2/viewer.html)!

Comment: Thannk you , this gives me hint